# Why \emph{} is not working in beamer?

Tags: math-mode, emphasis

I am making some slides for a presentation. I am copying parts of a texfile which I made earlier. The `\emph{}` command is not working in beamer (even though it is working in my original texfile).

For example, this code which is working in the original file is not working in beamer:

```
\begin{theorem}
{
 |\emph{Gal}(L|K)|=[F:K]
}
\end{theorem}
```

But this is working:

```
\begin{theorem}
{
 |Gal(L|K)|=[F:K]
}
\end{theorem}
```

But the 'Gal' is italic  (I want it to be straight).

Comment: By default, `\emph` works without problem within [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer). Can you provide a minimal example that replicates this problematic behaviour?

Comment: @Werner I edited the question. I have given the code in my question.

Comment: @learning_math: I should have been a bit more specific. Please read [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: In beamer this is a little tricky because of the fonts, so `\mathrm` might end up wrong. Since this is clearly a function I'd use `\operatorname ` if this is just a one of. Why is his math not in math mode?

Comment: @Schweinebacke `\text` should never be used like that even in beamer. So many users misuse this macro, we don't need another answer misusing it.

Comment: @Schweinebacke it is clearly a math function which is why I suggest operatorname. Then the OP can also learn why | is not suppose to be used to mark the absolute value (too large spacing)

Comment: @Schweinebacke in any case, theorems in beamer is in italic, so `\text` will be italic no matter how the OP writes it, math or not. Here the issue is just that `\emph` does not do **anti-italic** in an italic context.

Comment: The question cited in closing this question does not answer the question asked. I have encountered this same behavior.