# Commands \emph and \textit don't work correctly in beamer package

Tags: beamer, fonts

I'm new to beamer package but I think \emph and \textit don't work correctly here. The following code gives similar straight 'Texts'. I have read questions [Why \emph{} is not working in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366718/why-emph-is-not-working-in-beamer?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Beamer does not restore roman style for emph inside emph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89425/beamer-does-not-restore-roman-style-for-emph-inside-emph) but it's still not clear for me what is wrong.

I use version 3.58 of beamer package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\emph{Text}, \textit{Text}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is replacing `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` feasible?

Comment: Well, actually, I want to use cyrillic symbols in my presentation.

Comment: You may want to broaden your question, then, to ask how to (a) input and (b) display Cyrillic letters in a `beamer` document.

Comment: Try removing `\usepackage{times}`